# при нажатии на клавишу не меняется объект Swing

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class FieldPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    private JPanel squares[][] = null;
    private int currentRow = 0, currentColumn = 0;

    public FieldPanel() {
        setSize(600, 600);
        setCurrentRow(4);
        setCurrentColumn(0);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            System.out.println("UP");
            if (getCurrentRow() > 0) {
                setCurrentRow(getCurrentRow() - 1);
                repaint();
            }
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            System.out.println("Down");
            if (getCurrentRow() < squares.length - 1) {
                setCurrentRow(getCurrentRow() + 1);
                repaint();
            }
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            System.out.println("Left");
            if (getCurrentColumn() > 0) {
                setCurrentColumn(getCurrentColumn() - 1);
                repaint();
            }
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            System.out.println("Right");
            if (getCurrentColumn() < squares[0].length) {
                setCurrentColumn(getCurrentColumn() + 1);
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        squares = new JPanel[8][8];
        System.out.println("row: " + getCurrentRow() + " column: " + getCurrentColumn());

        super.paint(g);
        for(int i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < squares[0].length; j++) {
                squares[i][j] = new JPanel();
                if(i == getCurrentRow() && j == getCurrentColumn()) squares[i][j].add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/113.jpg"))));
                else if(j == squares[0].length - 2) squares[i][j].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                else squares[i][j].add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/114.png"))));
                this.add(squares[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getCurrentColumn() {
        return currentColumn;
    }

    public void setCurrentColumn(int currentColumn) {
        this.currentColumn = currentColumn;
    }

    public int getCurrentRow() {
        return currentRow;
    }

    public void setCurrentRow(int currentRow) {
        this.currentRow = currentRow;
    }
}
```

**Обновление**

Создаю обычную игру, где игрок должен пробежать поле (у меня это `JPanel[8][8]`). Игра управляется из клавиатуры кнопками up, down, right, left. Если пользователь, например, нажал вправо, картинка игрока заменяется травой, а картинка игрока появляется правее. Я переопредилил метод `paint()`, но при нажатии клавиши картинка фрейма не меняется. Подскажите, что я делаю не так.

```
public class RunningBackFrame extends JFrame{

    JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    FieldPanel footballField;

    public RunningBackFrame() {
        Dimension boardSize = new Dimension(600, 600);

        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        setPreferredSize(boardSize);
        setResizable(false);
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(boardSize);
        getContentPane().add(layeredPane);

        footballField = new FieldPanel();
        layeredPane.add(footballField);

        this.addKeyListener(footballField);
        pack();
    }



} // мой фрейм
```

Comment: По-моему, лучше просто прямо на панели рисовать. Сейчас у вас проблема в том, что вы бесконечно добавляете новые компоненты на панель, и когда в гриде заканчивается место (8х8), новые он просто не показывает. Вы можете сделать `this.removeAll()` перед циклами, и `this.revalidate()` после, но лучше или заранее создайте и заполните свой массив `JLabel`ами, и просто меняйте им фон и картинку (желательно не в `paint`), или рисуйте.

Comment: @zRrr Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Получилось именно то, что я и хотел